# Sampling from bivariate normal in python

Tags: python, numpy, distribution, random

I'm trying to create two random variables which are correlated with one another, and I believe the best way is to draw from a bivariate normal distribution with given parameters (open to other ideas).  The uncorrelated version looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
sigma = np.random.uniform(.2, .3, 80)
theta = np.random.uniform( 0, .5, 80)
```

However, for each one of the 80 draws, I want the sigma value to be related to the theta value.  Any thoughts?

Comment: what do you want the covariance matrix (rho) to be?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but shouldn't you be using normal instead of uniform for normal distribution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the built-in:  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mymeans = [13,5]  
>>> # stdevs = sqrt(5),sqrt(2)
>>> # corr = .3 / (sqrt(5)*sqrt(2) = .134
>>> mycov = [[5,.3], [.3,2]]   
>>> np.cov(np.random.multivariate_normal(mymeans,mycov,500000).T)
array([[ 4.99449936,  0.30506976],
       [ 0.30506976,  2.00213264]])
>>> np.corrcoef(np.random.multivariate_normal(mymeans,mycov,500000).T)
array([[ 1.        ,  0.09629313],
       [ 0.09629313,  1.        ]])
```

1. As shown, things get a little hairier if you have to adjust for not-unit variances)
2. more reference:  http://www.riskglossary.com/link/correlation.htm
3. To be real-world meaningful, the covariance matrix must be **symmetric** and must also be *positive definite* or *positive semidefinite* (it must be invertable).  Particular anti-correlation structures might not be possible.

Comment: Perfect -- given my mediocre statistical background, could you explain what the values in mycov are related to? I assume that the "5" and the "1" are the variances which correspond to each vector of interest?  Thanks again,

Comment: yes indeed!  5 and 1 are the variances, and .3 is the covariances.  If you just want correlations, you have to jigger it a bit more, as described.

Comment: Great answer! This is much easier than premultiplying a (Gaussian random) vector with a matrix to induce some covariances.

Answer (score 3):

`import multivariate_normal` from `scipy` can be used. Suppose we create random variables `x` and `y`:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

rv_mean = [0, 1]  # mean of x and y  
rv_cov = [[1.0,0.5], [0.5,2.0]]  # covariance matrix of x and y
rv = multivariate_normal.rvs(rv_mean, rv_cov, size=10000)
```

You have `x` from `rv[:,0]` and `y` from `rv[:,1]`. Correlation coefficients can be obtained from

```
import numpy as np
np.corrcoef(rv.T)
```

Answer (score 0):

The two normal distributions are defined by a mean and a variance:

```
means = [0, 0] # respective means
var_xx = 1 ** 2 # var x = std x squared
var_yy = 1 ** 2
```

The covariance between the two distributions is defined by a covariance matrix made of the variances and the two covariances. The two covariances x/y and y/x are equal:

```
import numpy as np
cov_xy = 0.5
cov = np.array([[var_xx, cov_xy],
                [cov_xy, var_yy]])
```

N pairs are drawn from the distributions using a random generator and the function `multivariate_normal`. Optional `check_valid='raise'` is used to check the covariance matrix is actually [symmetric and positive semi-definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix):

```
g = np.random.default_rng()
N = 100
pairs = g.multivariate_normal(means, cov, size=N, check_valid='raise')
```

As an example, let's plot these pairs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(pairs[:,0], pairs[:,1])
```

[image]